# SQL Server: where clause is being ignored

Tags: sql-server

The first condition was being ignored.

Sample table and records.

**Header** table:

```
ID  Title     Group
-------------------------
1   Header1   SERVICES
2   Header2   PACKAGING
3   Header3   COLS
```

**Line** table:

```
ID  HEADER_ID   Title   DEPARTMENT
-------------------------------------
1   1   LINE1   DEPARTMENT B
2   2   LINE2   DEPARTMENT M
3   2   LINE3   DEPARTMENT A
4   3   LINE4   DEPARTMENT C
```

User stories:

1. I want all headers that have these following groups not to be listed in the query.

   - SERVICES
   - PACKAGING
2. And also I want all headers where its LINES are on these following departments:

   - DEPARTMENT B
   - DEPARTMENT M

Here is the query:

```
SELECT HEADER.*
FROM HEADER
INNER JOIN LINE ON HEADER.ID = LINE.HEADER_ID
WHERE (HEADER.GROUP <> “SERVICES” OR HEADER.GROUP <> “PACKAGING”)
  AND (LINE.DEPARTMENT = “DEPARTMENT B” OR LINE.DEPARTMENT = “DEPARTMENT A”)
```

It's working if you remove the second where clause.

Comment: Shouldn't the join be ON HEADER.ID = LINE.HEADER_ID?

Comment: Yes, Sorry its a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider a sub-query to find all headers meeting your condition (and to also prevent duplicates that you'd have to use DISTINCT or GROUP BY eliminate):

```
SELECT *
FROM HEADER
WHERE Group NOT IN ('SERVICES', 'PACKAGING') 
    AND ID IN (SELECT Header_ID FROM LINE
        WHERE DEPARTMENT IN ('DEPARTMENT M', 'DEPARTMENT B'))
```